# What is the default timeout for httpRequest?

Tags: apex, rest, timeout

What is the default timeout for httpRequest. I have gone through [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) . But could not find the default timeout.

```
public class HttpCallout{
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void getContent(String url){
        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(2000); // What is the default if I am not adding this code.

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        String response = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(res.getBody(),'UTF-8');
        System.debug('***response****'+response);
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use any `community` tags unless you are actually asking questions related to the `Communities` feature.

Comment: I typed salesforce and It brings up community. dint think noted that is for cummunity in salesfroce. I took it general meaning .I will pick the right one next time. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: You don't need to let the rest of SFSE know your question is about Salesforce. It's the *Salesforce* Stack Exchange, so that information is 100% redundant. Either that, or your post is off topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm?search_text=default%20timeout):

> The default timeout is 10 seconds. A custom timeout can be defined for
>   each callout. The minimum is 1 millisecond and the maximum is 120,000
>   milliseconds.
>
> The maximum cumulative timeout for callouts by a single Apex
>   transaction is 120 seconds. This time is additive across all callouts
>   invoked by the Apex transaction.